# Javascript -value assignment updates the parent element?

Tags: javascript

In the below code, how afte assign the arr3 value to arr2 , it updates the arr1 too?

```
   var arr1 = "john".split('');
    var arr2 = arr1.reverse();
    var arr3 = "jones".split('');
    arr2.push(arr3);
    console.log("array 1: length=" + arr1.length + " last=" + arr1.slice(-1));
    console.log("array 2: length=" + arr2.length + " last=" + arr2.slice(-1));
```

EDIT: when i modify the code as below I am getting the same output

```
var arr1 = "john".split('');
var arr2 = arr1;
var arr3 = "jones".split('');
arr2.push(arr3);//arr1 updated
console.log("array 1: length=" + arr1.length + " last=" + arr1.slice(-1));
console.log("array 2: length=" + arr2.length + " last=" + arr2.slice(-1));
```

when i check the value of arr1 after the line arr2.push(arr3) it shows the value of arr3 also added.

Any way to restrict this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
arr1.reverse()
```

… reverses `arr1` and returns `arr1`, which is then assigned to `arr2` as a reference:

```
var arr2 = arr1.reverse();
```

What you want is a *copy* of `arr1`, which you can get by calling its `slice()` method:

```js
var arr1 = "john".split('');
var arr2 = arr1.slice().reverse();
var arr3 = "jones".split('');
arr2.push(arr3);
console.log("array 1: length=" + arr1.length + " last=" + arr1.slice(-1));
console.log("array 2: length=" + arr2.length + " last=" + arr2.slice(-1));
```

Comment: I am getting the same output without reverse also.

Comment: That's right, because `var arr2 = arr1` will assign `arr1` by reference to `arr2`.  Therefore, anything you do to `arr2` will also affect `arr1` (unless you explicitly set `arr2` equal to something else).  Using `slice()` gives you a copy instead of a reference.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must know that Object values in JavaScript are passed by reference and primitives are passed by value.

Having this in mind, now you know that `arr1` and `arr2` are referencing the same space in memory, so when you reverse `arr1` you are not creating a new reversed array, you are just reversing `arr1` and assigning it to `arr2`, so both variables are pointing to the same reversed array.

Now, if you want to create another array from `arr1` use `slice()`:

```
var arr2 = arr1.slice().reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.reverse() does not create a new array. Instead it replaces the elements in place:

> The reverse method reverses the elements of an Array object in place. It does not create a new Array object during execution.
>   If the array is not contiguous, the reverse method creates elements in the array that fill the gaps in the array. Each of these created elements has the value undefined.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3333858x(v=vs.94).aspx

Here is a simple example:

```
var arr = "Hello".split('');   // ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"] 
arr.reverse();                 // ["o", "l", "l", "e", "H"]
console.log(arr);              // ["o", "l", "l", "e", "H"]
```

Comment: In your code edit, calling  arr1 === arr2 would return true. This tells you that both variables point to the same array. Hence, is you change arr2 then arr1 is of course changed as well. With arr2.push(arr3); you are changing arr2 which points to the same array as arr1.

Answer (score 0):

`reverse()` works on the array it is invoked on .

```
var arr2 = arr1.reverse();
```

`arr2` here refers to the `arr1` after `arr1` was reversed.

Answer (score 0):

you can also clone array if it has referance to objects by stringify arr1 and then parse it

```js
var arr1 = "john".split('');
    var arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( arr1)).reverse();
    var arr3 = "jones".split('');
    arr2.push(arr3);
    alert("array 1: length=" + arr1.length + " last=" + arr1.slice(-1));
    alert("array 2: length=" + arr2.length + " last=" + arr2.slice(-1));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```